# Quasiparticle interference experiment - why backscattering is usually dominant?

Tags: experimental-physics, scattering, interference, quasiparticles

I am reading Avraham et. al (2018) [Quasiparticle Interference Studies of Quantum Materials](https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/abs/10.1002/adma.201707628) about quasi-particle interference (QPI) experiments. In the simplest case where they use QPI to study the surface of Cu, it is said that the dominant elastic scattering event will be back-scattering, where $\vec{k}_{i} = -\vec{k}_{f}$. I have difficulties in understanding this.

My attempt is that the probability for a certain elastic scattering event happening at energy $E$, where we start from a state with momentum $\vec{k}$ and then scatter to another state with momentum $\vec{k} + \vec{q}$, should be roughly written as
\begin{align}
|V(\vec{q})|^{2} \rho(\vec{k},E) \rho(\vec{k}+\vec{q},E),
\end{align}
where $\rho(\vec{k},E)$ is the density of state at momentum $\vec{k}$ and energy $E$, and $\vec{q}$ is the momentum transfer in the scattering event.

Let us assume a simple case that we have a scatterer with potential $V(\vec{r})=V_{0}\delta(\vec{r})$, then the Fourier transformation $V(\vec{q})$ is simply a constant. And therefore the dominant elastic scattering event at energy $E$, for a specific $\vec{q}$ will be the one that maximizes the *joint density of state* $\rho(\vec{k},E) \rho(\vec{k}+\vec{q},E)$ at energy $E$.

Let us also assume a symmetric dispersion with $E(\vec{k}) = \frac{\hbar^{2}|\vec{k}|^{2}}{2m}$. This means that $\rho(\vec{k},E)$ only depends on $|\vec{k}|$ and $E$. And so we can write
\begin{align}
\rho(\vec{k},E) = \rho(|\vec{k}|,E).
\end{align}
If all the above stuff I described above is fine, then we immediately conclude that given a energy $E$,
\begin{align}
\rho(\vec{k}_{1},E) \rho(\vec{k}_{1}',E) = \rho(\vec{k}_{2},E) \rho(\vec{k}_{2}',E)
\end{align}
as long as all of $\vec{k}_{1}$, $\vec{k}_{1}'$, $\vec{k}_{2}$ and $\vec{k}_{2}'$ lie on the Fermi surface defined by $E$, in other words, all of them satisfy
\begin{align}
E = \frac{\hbar^{2}|\vec{k}_{1}|^{2}}{2m} = \frac{\hbar^{2}|\vec{k}_{1}'|^{2}}{2m} = \frac{\hbar^{2}|\vec{k}_{2}|^{2}}{2m} = \frac{\hbar^{2}|\vec{k}_{2}'|^{2}}{2m}.
\end{align}
The key point here is that, all the scattering events will have the same probability and the back-scattering event does not seem to be the dominant one. $\vec{k}_{1}$ does not have to be equal to $-\vec{k}_{1}'$ and $\vec{k}_{2}$ does not have to be equal to $-\vec{k}_{2}'$ to get the same joint density of state $\rho(\vec{k},E) \rho(\vec{k}+\vec{q},E)$ for back-scattering event. In fact, they are all same, in the above calculation.

Are there any suggestion or reference about this? It seems like most of the literature said that the back-scattering event dominates. But I am curious about why this happen. I guess there are some other factors that can not be captured using the above simple calculation. Thanks!